# c++ csv data importing problems

Tags: c++, csv

I am a college student and as part of my final project for a c++ class we are assigned to read a csv file that has distance and force data and then find torque from it.  The problem that I am running into is how to actually get the data out of the csv file into a workable format.  Currently I have been trying to get it into a matrix, to do this though I will need to first determine the size of the csv file as it is supposed to take any size file.  This is the format of the data

Case 1,,,,,x_position (m),y_position (m),z_position (m),F_x (N),F_y (N),F_z (N)16.00,5.00,8.00,394.00,-18.00,396.0022.00,26.00,14.00,-324.00,-420.00,429.0028.00,25.00,21.00,73.00,-396.00,-401.006.00,9.00,12.00,-367.00,-137.00,-143.00

Also obviously the different data pieces (distance and forces) need to be put into different vectors or matrices.
This is what I have so far to try to find the number of lines in the file.

```
ifstream myfile("force_measurements.csv");
if(myfile.is_open()){
        string line;
        double num=0;
        getline(myfile, line);
        if(line==""){
            cout<<num<<endl;
            myfile.close();
        }
        else{
            num++;
        }
}
```

After this works how would you go about putting the data into a matrix? or would a different format be easier? vectors was my other though.

Comment: the file has to have some information on number of rows/columns in its header, otherwise you have no chance to get the dimensions right. Or is the matrix always quadratic?

Comment: There are always 6 columns of data.  The 3 dimensions and there 3 matching dimension forces

Answer (score 0):

```
// you need to include the proper headers here
class vec3D:
{
     double m_x, m_y, m_z;
 public:
     void Set(size_t indx, double val)
     {
         switch(indx)
         { 
             case 0:
                 m_x = val;
                 break;
             case 1:
                 m_y = val;
                 break;
             case 2:
                 m_z = val;
                 break;
             default:
                 std::cout << "index out of range" << std::endl;
         }
     }
     double magnitude() { return std::sqrt( m_x*m_x + m_y*m_y + m_z*m_y);}
};

int main()
{
     std::ifstream my_data_file ( "your_file_here.csv" );
     std::vector<std::array<vec3D, 2>> Pos_Forz;
     if ( ! my_data_file.is_open())
     {
          std::cout << "failure to open the file" <<std::endl;
          return -1;
     }
     std::string temp_str;
     double arr[6];
     std::array<vec3D,2> temp_3Dvec;
     while(!my_data_file.eof())
     {
         for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
         {
             getline(my_data_file, temp_str, ",");
             arr[i] = std::stod(temp_str);
         }
         getline(my_data_file, temp_str);
         arr[5] = std::stod(temp_str);
         for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
         { 
             for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
             {
                   temp_3Dvec[i].set(j, arr[i*3 + j]);
             }
         }
         Pos_Forz.push_back(temp_3Dvec);
     }
    for(auto e: Pos_Forz)
    {
      std::cout << " toque = " << (e[0].magnitude() * e[1].magnitude()) <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Fix what need to be fixed, and inspire yourself from this code, also stop asking this kinda of questions here, you need to read the HOW TO of posting

Answer (score -2):

You have multiple questions.  Here's something I used for loading items out of a csv.  This gets you started, and you can figure out whether further organization of the data is useful.  I personally have classes that take a tokenized line and create an instance of themselves with them.

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
typedef vector<string> csvLine;
void aFunction()
{
    string line;
    vector<csvLine> usedCollection;
    ifstream csvFile("myfile.csv", ios::in);
    if (!csvFile)
        return -1;

    while (getline(csvFile, line))
    {
        vector<string> tokenizedLine;
        boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > tk(
            line, boost::escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
        for (const string& str : tk)
        {
            tokenizedLine.push_back(str);
        }
        usedCollection.push_back(tokenizedLine);
    }
    csvFile.close();
}
```

And so `usedCollection` is a collection of `csvLines`, where each of those is a collection of strings broken up by the separator character.

Comment: this doesnt even compile

Comment: boost isn't easy to pull into new projects on my system.  It's still missing headers, but they are all standard.  (like <vector>)